# Using the following hashing method to store a database object

Tags: security, hash, base64, guid

I would like to create a valid variable identifier that can be used across any database object. It seems Oracle has the strictest requirements and [only allows 30 chars](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) for a (non-DB) object name, so something like `[_a-zA-Z]\W{,29}`. My thinking was to base32-encode an md5, such as:

```
>>> base64.b32encode(hashlib.md5(b'asdf').digest()).rstrip(b'=')
# b'SEXMQA5SZZE6JJKBA2GUSWVVOA'
# len=26
```

Does that seem like an acceptable approach?

Comment: What problem do you expect? As purely a matter of security hygiene you should use SHA-256 here, simply because you shouldn't put MD5 or SHA-1 into any new code (it is unlikely that there would be an actual security concern here; it is just good practice to avoid importing insecure protocols).  But sure; do you have a reason to believe there's a problem? (Remember that you can always use a subset of bits from a secure hash. Just because SHA-256 may output more bits than you want doesn't mean you have to use them all.)

Comment: But one problem is that base32 doesn't match your spec. It includes digits (and may even have a leading digit).

Comment: @RobNapier I see. So maybe if I have four extra chars I can add in: `id_` or something as a prefix?

Comment: sure; or just one `_`. I assume you mean that the actual requirement allows numbers?